# Java Tax Calculator problems

Tags: java

I am trying to create a income tax calculator in java, and i got it to run, but it freezes up when i try to put in my marital status. can anybody tell me what I am going wrong? any help would be greatly appreciated.
Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TaxCalculator {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final double RATE1 = 0.20;
        final double RATE2 = 0.25;
        final double RATE3 = 0.10;
        final double RATE4 = 0.15;
        final double RATE5 = 0.30;
        final double RATE1_SINGLE_LIMIT = 0;
        final double RATE2_MARRIED_LIMIT = 0;
        final double RATE3_COHABITATING_LIMIT = 20000;
        final double RATE4_COHABITATING_LIMIT = 50000;
        double tax1 = 0;
        double tax2 = 0;
        double tax3 = 0;
        double tax4 = 0;
        double tax5 = 0;

        //Enter Income
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please enter your income: ");
        double income = in.nextDouble();

        System.out.print("Please enter 's' for single, 'm' for married, or 'c' for cohabitating: ");
        String maritalStatus = in.next();

        //Calculate Taxes

        if (maritalStatus.equals("s"));
        //nested if

        if (income > RATE1_SINGLE_LIMIT) {
            tax1 = RATE1 * income;
        }

        if (maritalStatus.equals("m"));
        
        if (income > RATE2_MARRIED_LIMIT) {
            tax2 = RATE2 * income;
        }

        if (maritalStatus.equals("c"));
        
        if (income <= RATE3_COHABITATING_LIMIT) {
            tax3 = RATE3 * income;
        }   
        
        if (maritalStatus.equals("c"));
        
        if (income <= RATE4_COHABITATING_LIMIT) {
            tax4 = RATE4 * income;
        } else {
            tax5= RATE5 * income;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: These comparisons have no effect in the code: `if (maritalStatus.equals("s"));`.

Comment: How do  I fix that? sorry im new to java

Comment: @ErikKeener, are you running this app in some online Java compiler?  I was not able to reproduce the "freezing" issue

Comment: You have to step back and carefully research how that scanner works. For starters: when you dont understand what your code is doing, add print statements. like: do a `System.out.println("income is: " + income)` after the input. And then do one for the martialStatus. Your code doesnt "freeze", you simply arent using the scanner as you should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. fix your `if` statements and remove redundant `taxN` variables.
2. Add `in.nextLine()` after each Scanner entry.

.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TaxCalculator {
    static void calculate() {

        final double RATE1 = 0.20;
        final double RATE2 = 0.25;
        final double RATE3 = 0.10;
        final double RATE4 = 0.15;
        final double RATE5 = 0.30;
        final double RATE1_SINGLE_LIMIT = 0;
        final double RATE2_MARRIED_LIMIT = 0;
        final double RATE3_COHABITATING_LIMIT = 20000;
        final double RATE4_COHABITATING_LIMIT = 50000;
        double tax = 0;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        //Enter Income
        System.out.print("Please enter your income: ");
        double income = in.nextDouble();
        in.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Please enter 's' for single, 'm' for married, or 'c' for cohabitating: ");
        String maritalStatus = in.next();
        in.nextLine();

        //Calculate Taxes

        if (maritalStatus.equals("s") && income > RATE1_SINGLE_LIMIT) {
            tax = RATE1 * income;
        } else if (maritalStatus.equals("m") && income > RATE2_MARRIED_LIMIT) {
            tax = RATE2 * income;
        } else if (maritalStatus.equals("c") && income <= RATE3_COHABITATING_LIMIT) {
            tax = RATE3 * income;
        } else if (maritalStatus.equals("c") && income <= RATE4_COHABITATING_LIMIT) {
            tax = RATE4 * income;
        } else {
            tax = RATE5 * income;
        }

        System.out.print("Your tax is: " + tax);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String newResponse = "";
        do {
            calculate();
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Process another response?. Please enter 'y' for yes, or 'n' for no: ");
            newResponse = in.next();
            in.nextLine();
        } while (newResponse.equals("y"));

    }
}
```

Comment: You answer was so helpful, but i just found out I have to add something to it,  i am supposed to add an option to this program that " should allow the user to process additional customers as long as he/she enter y in response to a "Process another response" prompt. i get that I will need to put in a print command for the prompt, but how will i get it to allow the user to enter multiple customers?

Comment: Im just going to post it as a new question so that way if you would like to answer then i could accept you answer again.  once again thanks so much for your help

Comment: @ErikKeener Please do that. I'll be happy to help.

Comment: @Eric Keener  I've modified the code to fit your needs.

Comment: oh wow thank you so much! i just posted my question a moment ago ( because I had to wait 90 minutes to post again) but if you put your answer on my new post i would be glad to accept it! thank you for all your help

Comment: @ErikKeener I've fixed some bug in the code. Please share the question post link.

Comment: @ErikKeener I've seen it. Posted!

Answer (score 1):

Put `in.nextLine();` after `double income = in.nextDouble();` and after `String maritalStatus = in.next();`. This is one of the solutions. The `nextLine` method will consume the *new line (line feed)* character, which is created in the input buffer by hitting Enter.

Comment: Ok i added it both places, but i still have the same issue. it stops after i try to enter marital status

Answer (score 0):

The nested `if` statements should look  like this (note inverted comparison of String literal to the data input by user):

```java
if ("s".equals(maritalStatus)) {
    if (income > RATE1_SINGLE_LIMIT) {
        tax1 = RATE1 * income;
    }
} else if ("m".equals(maritalStatus)) {
    if (income > RATE2_MARRIED_LIMIT) {
        tax2 = RATE2 * income;
    }
} else if ("c".equals(maritalStatus)) {
    if (income <= RATE3_COHABITATING_LIMIT) {
        tax3 = RATE3 * income;
    }   
    if (income <= RATE4_COHABITATING_LIMIT) {
        tax4 = RATE4 * income;
    } else {
        tax5= RATE5 * income;
    }
}

// add output line
System.out.println("marital status:" +  maritalStatus + "; income=" + income + " -> " + Arrays.asList(tax1, tax2, tax3, tax4, tax5));
```

Output:

```
Please enter your income: 3300
Please enter 's' for single, 'm' for married, or 'c' for cohabitating: m
marital status:m; income=3300.0 -> [0.0, 825.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

Comment: Doesnt answer the question. "Freezing" happens because the console is waiting for input This has NOTHING to do with the not-so-great if blocks afterwards.

Comment: @GhostCat, I could not reproduce "freezing" issue

Comment: Then the OP might have changed the code in the meantime. Anyway, then we are looking at "close for not reproducable"